# Where is _≡⟨_⟩_ Agda standard lib?

Tags: agda

I read such a piece of code in plfa.

```
import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality as Eq
open Eq using (_≡_; refl; cong; sym)
open Eq.≡-Reasoning using (begin_; _≡⟨⟩_; _≡⟨_⟩_; _∎)
```

but `_≡⟨_⟩_` is not in PropositionalEquality

```
The module Eq.≡-Reasoning doesn't export the following: _≡⟨_⟩_
when scope checking the declaration
  open Eq.≡-Reasoning using (begin_; _≡⟨⟩_; _≡⟨_⟩_; _∎)
```

I only find it in `Function.Related` and `Relation.Binary.HeterogeneousEquality`. What is happening?

Answer (score 5):

`_≡⟨_⟩_` is a syntax notation for `step-≡` as you can see in [`Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality.Core`](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/v1.1/Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality.Core.html#2499).

So if you want to control what you are importing, you need to refer to `step-≡`
instead.

Comment: Sorry, I still don’t understand... I just want to import `_≡⟨_⟩_`, what import statement should I write?

Comment: replace `_≡⟨_⟩_` with `step-≡` in your import statement from your question.

Comment: `open ≡-Reasoning`